# Importing a module in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, python-module

I'm not sure how importing module in python really works in Azure Databricks. First, I was able to make it work using the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Workspace/Repos/Github Repo/sparkling-to-databricks/src")
from utils.some_util import *
```

I was able to use the imported function. But then I restarted the cluster and this would not work even though the path is in sys.path.

I also tried the following:

```
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("/Workspace/Repos/Github Repo/my-repo/src/utils/some_util.py")
```

This did not work either. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here and suggest a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Is your code is in the same repository that are you adding to `sys.path`?

Comment: Yes, the notebook I'm trying to import it in is in the same repo

Comment: is it notebbok or python file? notebooks can't be imported

Comment: The function is in a file. The imports are in a Notebook

Comment: What is Databricks Runtime version? What version is selected for "Files in Repos" in the admin console?

Comment: It seems this was the issue. I changed the version in both to the latest and it is working now.